# Faulty upgrade from 10.4 to 10.10 Can I redo the upgrade without erasing all the existing mess?

Tags: upgrade

I happily used 10.4 for abouit six months.  When I upgraded to 10.10 my Update Manager stopped working and at last count there were about 250 updates lined up and waiting.  Also my sound configurations misfired (It won't accept my Logitech headset.)

I tried to follow advice from some other forums which didn't work.  I also tried all sorts of nonsense myself.  I think that now the best thing to do would be to either erase or overwrite whatever is there and start over with 10.10 anew.  I can either do without or save whatever might be lost.  Most of my important stuff is in the Google cloud.  What might the best way for me to get back to work?

Please help,  I have had to go back to XP and it is driving me nuts.

Mike

Answer (score 2):

I had the same thing happen to me. Using help from IRC, here's what I did:

Boot from a live CD. Open a terminal. Type:

```
sudo su root
mount [your root partition] /mnt
chroot /mnt
aptitude update
aptitude upgrade
```

Then reboot.

If those last two lines don't work after you reboot back into your installation, repeat the first three lines and then type:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo dpkg -configure -a
sudo apt-get upgrade --fix-broken
```

Comment: Can you fix the `-` in your second chunk of code? Some of them are supposed to be `--` (e.g. `--fix-broken`)

Answer (score 0):

Well, If you're inclined to re-install and you have backups.
I suggest the 3 partition custom layout...

```
/      <-- opinions vary, but 12 to 20G
/swap  <-- opinions vary, but safe at 1.5x RAM
/home  <-- the rest, or so...
```

I have a 100G HD chopped up with a 40G /sda1 as "/"
2G sda2 as /swap (I have 4 gig of RAM but only sees 3.
24G sda3 as /home with 26G unallocated for dual booting craziness.

This way, if it happens again, re-install and choose custom partitions, 
assign the /swap and /home (**without** formatting them) and install to / (with formatting).
Never lose your data again.

and oh yeah, backup, Backup, BACKUP! :)